# SQL Get Only Most Recent Record for A User

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to write a sql query to get all of the most recent responses for a student in a classroom. I basically want to show just their most recent response, not all of their responses. I have the query to get all of the responses and order them, however I can't figure out the part where it only grabs that user's most recent record.

Below is the query I have to this point. You can see from the sample data in the image it is pulling back all responses. What I basically want is either just the most recent for a particular student OR possibly just showing the max attempt for a particular Lesson/Page number combo. I have tried playing around with partition and group bys but I haven't found the right combination yet.

```
SELECT U.UserName, C.Name AS 'ClassroomName', U.FirstName, U.LastName, L.Name AS 'LessonName', P.PageNumber, R.Attempt, R.Created
FROM Responses R
INNER JOIN ClassroomUsers CU ON CU.UserId = R.UserId
INNER JOIN Classrooms C ON C.Id = CU.ClassroomId
INNER JOIN Questions Q ON Q.Id = R.QuestionId
INNER JOIN Pages P ON P.Id = Q.PageId
INNER JOIN Lessons L ON L.Id = P.LessonId
INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.Id = CU.UserId
WHERE CU.ClassroomId IN (
    SELECT CU.ClassroomId
    FROM ClassroomUsers CU
    WHERE CU.UserId = @UserId
)
ORDER BY R.Created DESC
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite way of doing this is using `Row_Number()` which will number each row based upon the criteria you set - In your case, you'd partition by `U.UserName` since you want one row returned for each user and order by `R.Created DESC` to get the latest one.

That being the case, you'd only want to get back the rows that have `RN=1`, so you query that out as follows:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.UserName ORDER BY R.Created DESC) AS RN
     ,U.UserName, C.Name AS 'ClassroomName', U.FirstName, U.LastName, L.Name AS 'LessonName', P.PageNumber, R.Attempt, R.Created
    FROM Responses R
    INNER JOIN ClassroomUsers CU ON CU.UserId = R.UserId
    INNER JOIN Classrooms C ON C.Id = CU.ClassroomId
    INNER JOIN Questions Q ON Q.Id = R.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN Pages P ON P.Id = Q.PageId
    INNER JOIN Lessons L ON L.Id = P.LessonId
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.Id = CU.UserId
    WHERE CU.ClassroomId IN (
        SELECT CU.ClassroomId
        FROM ClassroomUsers CU
        WHERE CU.UserId = @UserId
    )
)


SELECT * FROM cte WHERE RN = 1
```

Hope that makes sense / helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems to do the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is using the **WITH TIES** clause.

**Example**

```
SELECT top 1 with ties
    U.UserName
  , C.Name AS 'ClassroomName'
  , U.FirstName
  , U.LastName
  , L.Name AS 'LessonName'
  , P.PageNumber
  , R.Attempt
  , R.Created
FROM Responses R
INNER JOIN ClassroomUsers CU ON CU.UserId = R.UserId
INNER JOIN Classrooms C ON C.Id = CU.ClassroomId
INNER JOIN Questions Q ON Q.Id = R.QuestionId
INNER JOIN Pages P ON P.Id = Q.PageId
INNER JOIN Lessons L ON L.Id = P.LessonId
INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.Id = CU.UserId
WHERE CU.ClassroomId IN (
      SELECT CU.ClassroomId
        FROM ClassroomUsers CU
        WHERE CU.UserId = @UserId
      )
Order By ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.UserName ORDER BY R.Created DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This query also seems to pull back the information I was looking for.

Comment: @DBatPS Always happy to help